# toad formatting comma separate new line

Tags: sql, format, toad

I want to change toad format style
but I can't find it. please

view - toad options - formatter
What should I do?

```
SELECT LPAD (' ', 2 * (LEVEL - 1), '-') || '->' || LEVEL hierarchy
  ,IC ITEM_CODE
  ,PIC PARENT_ITEM_CODE
  ,DQ DEMAND_QUANTITY
  ,UNIT
  ,LOSS
  ,TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (BASE.TD) - overdue.OD_DELAY) TARGET_DATE
  ,NQ NEED_QUANTITY
  ,MS MSIGN
  ,ONO ORDER_NUM
  FROM base INNER JOIN overdue ON BASE.LV = OVERDUE.OD_LV
START WITH IC = 'TK-01'
CONNECT BY PRIOR IC = PIC;
```

This style for like this
Don't separate the line after comma and if the characters is full 80 in one line
make new line

```
select lpad(' ' , 2*(level-1), '-') || '->'|| LEVEL hierarchy, IC ITEM_CODE,
PIC PARENT_ITEM_CODE, DQ DEMAND_QUANTITY, UNIT, LOSS,
to_char(to_date(BASE.TD)-overdue.OD_DELAY) TARGET_DATE,
NQ NEED_QUANTITY, MS MSIGN, ONO ORDER_NUM
from base INNER JOIN overdue ON BASE.LV = OVERDUE.OD_LV
start with IC='TK-01'
connect by prior IC = PIC;
```

Comment: Which select is your starting statement and which is the desired format you would like? It is not clear to me from your question.

Comment: sorry, second thing is which I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired format doesn't look very formatted to me. In particular there is no indent before fields that have been wrapped to lines 2, 3, and 4. That aside you can configure some things you ask for.

In formatter options...

- Right Margin - Select the Spacing, Margins tree node. Set it to 80.
- Comma Placement - Select the List Arrangements, Commas tree node. Set that to Trailing.
- Column Arrangement - Select the List Arrangements, List Defaults tree node. Set the dropdown to Wrapped. **Look at the "SELECT list + INTO variables" node. If that is set to "Default" then modify the List Defaults as I said, but if it's overriding the List Defaults option then set your "SELECT list + INTO variables" option to Wrapped.

I believe this covers much of what you ask for, but just poke around in the formatter options. There is a lot in there and it's all pretty well explained with examples for most of it.